# Incremental autofill in googlesheet

Tags: google-sheets

I want to make a table with every 3rd row from the datasource.

```
1st cell: =TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE($B1," ",REPT(" ",20)),20))
2nd cell: =TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE($B4," ",REPT(" ",20)),20))
3rd cell: =TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE($B7," ",REPT(" ",20)),20))
...
```

I want cells to be auto filled with this pattern {B1,B4,B7,B10,B13..1+3x}

But when I select first three cells and try autofill, the spreadsheet does this

```
1st cell: =TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE($B1," ",REPT(" ",20)),20))
2nd cell: =TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE($B4," ",REPT(" ",20)),20))
3rd cell: =TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE($B3," ",REPT(" ",20)),20))
4th cell: =TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE($B4," ",REPT(" ",20)),20))
5th cell: =TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE($B7," ",REPT(" ",20)),20))
6th cell: =TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE($B6," ",REPT(" ",20)),20))
...
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: achieved what I wanted by adding a sequential columns and use that with `=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(INDIRECT(G6)," ",REPT(" ",20)),20))`. But I still want to know if there's an auto fill option because Excel does have this incremental function.

Comment: Are you trying to fill vertically or horizontally? In other words, in the resulting table is the value from B4 beneath the value from B1 or to the right of it?

Comment: Also, while we can't see your data and don't know your end goal with the individual formulas, it *seems* like you are just trying to extract the last word or string after the last space per string. If that is the case, there are easier ways to do that.

Comment: I'm sorting the data vertically and yes I only need last words.

Comment: I suspect there is more to your end goal. But seeing as I can only address what you've shared, see my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear a full column (say, Col C, for the sake of explanations here). Then place the following formula in C1 (or in C2 if you want to place a header in C1):

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY({IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B:B,"\S+$"))},"WHERE Col1 Is Not Null SKIPPING 3"))`

This one formula should produce all results in one go, no dragging down.

`REGEXEXTRACT` will attempt to pull `"\S+$"` from each cell in `B:B` (that is, "all non-space characters to the end of the string"). If this cannot be found in any cell (e.g., a null cell), then `IFERROR` will return null instead of an error.

`QUERY` then acts on this, returning every 3rd entry for all non-null results.

Comment: You're welcome. Whenever you get to feeling that some solution you're making is getting complicated... there's probably an easier way.